# Doctrine filter not working on itemOperations (Api-Platform)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

**API Platform version(s) affected**: 2.6.8

**Description**

In a project which uses PostgreSQL and API-Platform, I need to filter all records by a locale string. A doctrine filter is my preferred choice to do so.

This is the filter:

```
class LocaleFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    public const LOCALE_FILTER_NAME = 'locale_filter';

    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias): string
    {
        if (!$targetEntity->reflClass->implementsInterface(LocalizedEntityInterface::class)) {
            return '';
        }

        return $targetTableAlias . '.locale = ' . $this->getParameter('locale');
    }
}
```

The parameter `locale` will be set on each onKernelRequest event, the locale is the value of the header `X-Locale`:

```
    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $locale = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('X-Locale');

        $this->setFilterLocale($locale);
    }

    private function setFilterLocale(string $locale): void
    {
        if (!$this->entityManager->hasFilters()) {
            return;
        }

        $localeFilter = $this->entityManager->getFilters()->getFilter(LocaleFilter::LOCALE_FILTER_NAME);

        $localeFilter->setParameter('locale', $locale);
    }
```

Now, when I send a request to a collectionOperations endpoint, such as `http://example.com/products` with the `X-Locale` header value `de_DE`, the filter is working and I get a response which contains only the according data in `de_DE`. When I send a request with locale `fr_FR`, I get a response with data in `fr_FR`.

But, when I send a request with the same `X-Locale` header to a itemOperations endpoint like `http://example.com/products/<a-existing-id>` I'm getting the error message `The parameter "locale" is not set` which comes from doctrine.

After investigating that issue, I can say that it works when I override the default `ItemDataProvider` from API-platform:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataProvider;

[...]

class ItemDataProvider implements ItemDataProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        private readonly RequestStack $requestStack,
    ) {
    }

    public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, ?string $operationName = null, array $context = []): object
    {
        $locale = $this->requestStack->getMainRequest()->headers->get('X-Locale');

        if ($this->entityManager->hasFilters()) {
            $localeFilter = $this->entityManager->getFilters()->getFilter(LocaleFilter::LOCALE_FILTER_NAME);

            $localeFilter->setParameter('locale', $locale);
        }

        $query = $this->entityManager->getRepository($resourceClass)
            ->createQueryBuilder('x')
            ->where('x.publicId = :pubid')
            ->setParameter('pubid', $id)
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

But is still required to set the filter value again in "my own" ItemDataProvider. If I delete the first 7 lines of the method `getItem` of the ItemDataProvider, I get the same error from above.

That doesn't make sense like that, does it? It seems like Api-Platform overrides the Doctrine filters in the default ItemDataProvider and make them useless. Howewer, I didn't found the reason for that issue.

Overriding the ItemDataProvider is a working workaround, but I don't think it's a good one, since the cause is more likely a bug and that way some features of Api-Platform are no longer present in the whole project.

Comment: Have you tried to experiment with https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#manual-service-and-attribute-registration 
Maybe adding API platform service tag to your existing filter would work? On the other hand, You may try to change the priority of Your LocaleFilter service

Comment: I don't need a Api-Platform filter which must be set on each entity, I need a doctrine filter which works globally for that project.

Comment: I just faced a similar problem (SQLFilter working for itemOperations but not for collectionOperations + pagination activated). Thanks to the @TomaszBuczeń answer I've set the priority of my listener to fix that. In my case, it must be higher than 4 to be executed before the api_platform.listener.request.read listener and lower than 8 to be executed after the security listener. Note that I'm talking about the kernel.request listener priority and not the SQLFilter (which does not need to be declared as service)